# Building from sources on debian 10 with cuda 9.1, cudnn 7.1

Tags: tensorflow

Trying to build tensorflow 1.9 on debian 10 with cuda 9.1.85 
and cudnn 7.1.4.18

When using gcc-6 as the compiler and build command

```
bazel build --verbose_failures --config=opt --config=cuda --cxxopt="-D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0"  //tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package
```

I get

```
INFO: From Compiling external/nccl_archive

/src/libwrap.cu.cc:                                                                                    
/usr/lib/cuda/include/cuda_fp16.h(2958): error: identifier "__float2half_rn" is undefined                                                       

/usr/lib/cuda/include/cuda_fp16.h(3000): error: identifier "__float2half_rn" is undefined                                                       

2 errors detected in the compilation of "/tmp/tmpxft_000070b1_00000000-6_libwrap.cu.cpp1.ii".
```

Answer (score 0):

This was happening as the build was finding some cuda headers left over from a previous cuda 8.0 installation and these functions are not implemented there. After cleaning up these the build completed successfully.